# Does a pseudoscalar commute or anti-commute with a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, geometric-algebras

It seems to me the answer depends on the number of dimensions.

---

Suppose 3D:

$$
I=e_1e_2e_3
$$

then

$$
e_1I = e_1e_1e_2e_3 = -e_1e_2e_1e_3 = e_1e_2e_3e_1=Ie_1
$$

---

But if 2D:

$$
I=e_1e_2
$$

then

$$
e_1I=e_1e_1e_2=-e_1e_2e_1=-Ie_1
$$

---

Is this correct, it depends on if the algebra is odd or even dimensions? I have read a couple of books on geometric algebra, but I never notice this distinction being mentioned. I am afraid I may be doing something incorrect here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that this depends on the dimension:

$$ v I = (-1)^{N-1} I v, $$

where $v$ is any vector, and the "unit" pseudoscalar $ I = e_1 \cdots e_N $ is constructed by some ordered product of orthonormal basis vectors.

I've definitely seen this in GA literature.  I could be wrong, but think that "GA for physicists" was one such place.

Comment: Yes, Doran and Lasenby state  on page 36 of the book you mention that "[...] the pseudoscalar commutes with all vectors in three dimensions:
$Ia = aI$.
This is always the case for the pseudoscalar in spaces of odd dimension. In even dimensions, the pseudoscalar anticommutes with all vectors, as we have already seen in two dimensions."